# Is there a readable proof of the fact that the filled Julia set $K_c$ of a quadratic polynomial is a Cantor set if $f_c^n(0)$ goes to $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I found some proofs online but I don't consider them acceptable.

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf
there is a "proof" (page 22) that doesn't satisfy me.
I don't see why the branches of the inverses are Lipschitz.

http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/IM/MATH2916/r/Long_Essay.pdf (page 5)
This proof does not satisfy me AT ALL! Because the construction does not remind me of the construction of the Cantor set, since when I construct the Cantor set i know EXACTLY how much I'm removing at each stage.

https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f358061116.pdf (page 22)
This proof is not convincing since it doesn't tell what really is "Mod" and it relies on results that are not proved. This whole paper is full of mistakes and imprecisions.

https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/complex-dynamics-carleson.pdf (page 67)
The proof relies on a lot of powerful theorems proved in chapter one. I know that they are useful but the definition of Julia set is hard to understand and different from the one I have.

How come that for such a result that is mentioned everywhere as the "Fundamental Dichotomy" is almost impossible to find a decent proof?

Comment: Ok. We know that there is a closed disk such that the intersection of its preimages is $K_c$ and such that every preimage is contained in that disk. Having an infinite number of connected components means that every connected component has 0 measure...
And now?
I have to show that there are no paths.

Comment: I learned complex dynamics when *books* were still all the rage. Section 16.3 of Bob Devaney's *A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems* contains a very readable proof of the fact that the Julia set of $f_c$ is a Cantor set if $|c|>2$. That's not quite as strong the statement that you're looking to prove but it's a good start and should prepare you well for a higher level book, like Beardon's *Iteration of Rational Functions*, where the complete proof can be found.